# Turning a string of a bunch of words into a list with all the words separated

Tags: python, string, split

So I have a huge string of words separated by spaces and tabs and was wondering what I could do to quickly append each individual word to a list.

EX.

```
x = "hello Why You it     from the"
list1 = ['hello', 'why', 'you', 'it','from', 'the']
```

The string has tabs and multiple spaces varying between words and I just need a quick solution instead of manually fixing the problem

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> x = "hello Why You it from the"
>>> x.split()
['hello', 'Why', 'You', 'it', 'from', 'the']
>>> x = "hello                    Why You     it from            the"
>>> x.split()
['hello', 'Why', 'You', 'it', 'from', 'the']
>>>
```

Without any arguments, the method defaults to splitting on whitespace characters.

---

I just noticed that all of the strings in your example list are lowercase.  If this is needed, you can call [`str.lower`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) before `str.split`:

```
>>> x = "hello Why You it from the"
>>> x.lower().split()
['hello', 'why', 'you', 'it', 'from', 'the']
>>>
```

Comment: What about `x.lower().split()`?

Comment: @arshajii - Ha, I was just posting that. :)

Comment: I'll give you a +1 for spotting that the list was all lowercase, though.

Answer (score 2):

[`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) should do it:

```
>>> x = "hello Why You it from the"
>>> x.split()
['hello', 'Why', 'You', 'it', 'from', 'the']
```

If you want all lowercase (as @iCodez also points out):

```
>>> x.lower().split()
['hello', 'why', 'you', 'it', 'from', 'the']
```

---

From the link above:

> If `sep` is not specified or is `None`, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.

`sep` is the first argument of `split()`.